# Presto average window function

Tags: sql, window-functions, presto

I have a table that looks like the following:

```
+---------+-------------------+-------+
| merchant|time               |amount |
+---------+-------------------+-------+
| 1       |2020-04-01 10:15:01|   1234|
| 2       |2020-04-01 10:15:02|     50|
| 1       |2020-04-01 10:15:15|    820|
| 1       |2020-04-01 10:15:20|     29|
| 2       |2020-04-01 10:15:21|    260|
+---------+-------------------+-------+
```

I'm looking to get the average number of transactions per minute per merchant.

I can do something like

```
select
  merchant,
  avg(transactions_per_minute)
from (
  select
    merchant,
    date_trunc('minute', time) as time,
    count(*) as transactions_per_minute
  from transactions
  group by 1, 2
)
```

but is there any way to do it with a window function? I'm imagining something like

```
select
  merchant,
  avg(count(*) over (partition by date_trunc('minute', time)) as transactions_per_minute
from transactions
group by 1
```

but this throws the error `Cannot nest window functions inside aggregation 'avg'`

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do:

```
select merchant,
       (count(*) over (partition by merchant) /
        count(distinct date_trunc('minute', time)) over (partition by merchant)
       )
from transactions t;
```

I don't recall if Presto supports `COUNT(DISTINCT)` as a window function.  If not:

```
select merchant,
       (count(*) over (partition by merchant) /
         (dense_rank() over (partition by merchant order by date_trunc('minute', time)) +
          dense_rank() over (partition by merchant order by date_trunc('minute', time) desc)
       )
from transactions t;
```

Note:  This does exactly what your query does (or would with the final `group by`) -- it ignores minutes with no transactions.  If you want to include those then ask a *new* question.